# Does the XP penalty for non-favored class apply to prestige classes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, class

In D&D 3.5, a character with multiple classes suffers an XP penalty if two of their classes are more than one level apart, but favored class is ignored for that purpose. (*Player's Handbook*, p.60).

Do prestige classes count for this purpose?

For example, a dwarf level 7 cleric takes a level in warpriest. Does he now suffer an XP penalty because his two classes, cleric and warpriest, are more than one level apart, and neither of them is his favored class? Or are prestige classes ignored for the purpose of the multiclassing XP penalty?

Comment: If there's a specific unusual case or some kooky scenario that you had in mind that the linked question doesn't address, please edit the question appropriately. (I *hate* putting questions on hold.)

Comment: No, you're correct, this is a duplicate. Thanks for linking me to the correct answer.